# How to Unmarshal and Marshal YAML in Go, while preserving white space?

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I have a YAML like

```
data:
  label1:
    - someval1
    - someval2
  label2:
    - otherval1
    - otehrval2
```

Using YAML parser "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

```
yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlStr), &yamlObj)

# Some works and changes to yamlObj

s, _ := yaml.Marshal(&yamlObj)
fmt.Println(string(s))
```

This outputs:

```
data:
  label1:
  - someval1
  - someval2
  label2:
  - otherval1
  - otehrval2
```

The resulted YAML is correct but for my task I need lists (`- values`) indented as in original YAML. Is there a way to preserve those spaces and new lines?

Comment: Why do you need the original indentation?

Comment: When you unmarshal the YAML text into a Go value, the indentation info is lost (not stored in memory), so marshaling it again can't reproduce the same indentation if it wasn't standard.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be very difficult to keep the original format. But as a workaround you can marshal your struct in a format which is near by your input format.

`gopkg.in/yaml.v3` marshals in a more matching way as `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`

here is a little example:
https://play.golang.org/p/gjxR83P7p0F
Output:

```
V2: 
data:
  label1:
  - someval1
  - someval2
  label2:
  - otherval1
  - otehrval2

V3: 
data:
    label1:
        - someval1
        - someval2
    label2:
        - otherval1
        - otehrval2
```